# W subspace of $\mathbb{R^4}$ with $\mbox{dim}W = 3$ and $U =\cdots $. Find $\mbox{dim} U+W$ and $\mbox{dim} U\cap W$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $W$ be a subspace of $\mathbb{R^4}$ with $\mbox{dim}W = 3$ and $U
>  = \mbox{span}((1,2,1,3),(3,1,-1,4))$. Find $\mbox{dim} U+W$ and $\mbox{dim} U\cap W$

Well, so $\mbox{dim } U = 2$, clearly, and $\mbox{dim }W = 3$. But the exercise solution says that $\mbox{dim} U + W = 4$ **(why)?**

Also, by the formula:

$$\mbox{dim } (U+W) + \mbox{dim } (U\cap W) = \mbox{dim } U + \mbox{dim }W$$
then shouldn't $\mbox{dim }U\cap V$ be $1$? My book says it's $0$.

Update:

Well, in fact, the exercise says that $W$ is the subspace of the previous exercise:

> Let $W$ and $U$ be subspaces of $\mathbb{R^4}$ of dimension $3$. Which
>    dimensions can $W + U$ have if $\mbox{span}(W\cap U) =
>  \mbox{span}((1,2,1,0),(-1,1,0,1), (1,5,2,1))$

I don't know if information from this previous exercise makes a difference.

Comment: @GitGud $V$ should be $W$

Comment: $\dim U+W \leq \dim \mathbb{R}^4$ since it is a subspace. $\dim U \cap W$ should be one.

Comment: I don't see how the premises of this problem precludes the possibility $U \subset W$ in which case the book's answer is incorrect.

Comment: @kahen I updated the question. Would you mind to take a look?